# angular-read-more plugin console issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, console.log

I am using this plugin for manipulating my paragraph text for 'show less' and 'show more' text using angular.
No JavaScript requires for using this plugin, my HTML looks like this:

```
<p hm-read-more hm-text="{{item.data.content}}"
       hm-limit="350" hm-more-text="..read more" hm-less-text="..show less" hm-dots-class="dots" hm-link-class="links"
       class="readmore-para">
    </p>
```

Here is the link for plugin: https://github.com/ismarslomic/angular-read-more
It's working fine, but whenever I click on the 'show more' or 'show less' or even when the plugin is initiated it populate my browser console with messages. Here is the snap of console.
[image]

I don't know what to do, there are no such issues created by anyone on github when using this plugin. It is disturbing my console. Thank you.

Comment: I am using angular 1.4.14

Comment: [they have explicitly disabled debug Log](https://github.com/ismarslomic/angular-read-more/blob/master/src/readmore.js#L7) not sure why it is happening for you.. can you create a plunker/fiddle reproducing this?

Comment: Okay then, let me try.

Comment: It is not showing on online console. Here is the codepen demo link: 
http://codepen.io/ismarslomic/pen/yYMvrz?editors=0001

Comment: yes, so check for versions of library and how you are using it..

Comment: Not able to find any solution yet. Thanks anyway.